# Нужна ли запятая: "...простой, но вместе с этим невероятно глубокий(,) тезис"

Tags: пунктуация

*Если описать суть вкратце, то фундаментом моей работы является один очень простой, но вместе с этим невероятно глубокий(,) тезис.*

Нужна ли запятая в данном месте?

Answer (score 5):

Указанная запятая не ставится (предложение  отредактировано): Если описать суть вкратце, то фундаментом моей работы является **один очень простой, но вместе с тем весьма значимый** тезис.

[**Розенталь**  § 12. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные неповторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100,4#pp100)

После последнего однородного члена предложения, присоединяемого **противительным или подчинительным союзом** **и не заканчивающего собой предложения,** запятая не ставится (т. е. последний однородный член не обособляется): Не род, а ум поставлю в воеводы (П.); Каждый вечер солнце садилось в море, а не в тучи и было при этом клюквенного цвета (Ю. К.); Они получили **небольшую, но удобную** квартиру; Поставлена трудная, зато интересная задача;  Получены важные, хотя и не итоговые сведения.

Comment: Как вы определяете, что это не уточнение, которое отделяется запятыми? Имеет ли решающее значение тип союза (противительный, а не подчинительный), Сравните: *Актуальная, даже если не совсем новая, тема заслуживает внимания*. (Здесь подчинительный союз)

Comment: У Розенталя: Уточняющие определения могут присоединяться посредством подчинительных союзов: Неодолимая, хотя и тихая, сила увлекала меня. Если определение, присоединяемое ПОДЧИНИТЕЛЬНЫМ союзом, является однородным по отношению к предшествующему определению и не носит характера уточнения (СМЫСЛОВОГО И ИНТОНАЦИОННОГО), то после него запятая не ставится: Перед нами поставлена трудная, зато интересная задача. Разграничение этих случаев зависит от воли пишущего.http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

Comment: Вот и решаем. По смыслу они ближе к однородным, связаны отношением противопоставления. Значимость тезиса вряд ли стоит относить на второй план и считать уточнением.  С другой стороны, распространенность второго определения  не способствует его интонационному обособлению в предложении такой структуры (после длинной вставки  будет следовать  всего одно слово).

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не нужна запятая. Здесь обычное словосочетание (глубокий тезис), зачем между словами ставить запятую? Это не однородные члены, здесь нет уточнения.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что "простой" и "глубокий" - не однородные члены?